# use of unassigned local variable mvc model

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

There is an error occured when i declare variable of model class EmailModel 
use of unassigned local variable

```
EmailModel emailModel;
string Data = RenderPartialViewToString(this, "ChangePasswordemail", emailModel);
string name = WebSecurity.CurrentUserName;
Data = Data.Replace("Name", emailModel.FirstName);
Data = Data.Replace("Email", emailModel.Email);
```

Comment: You should always write the Exception you're having too. Besides, why are you using an unassigned model? The error is telling you to assign your model, why you don't do it?

Comment: *There is an error occured when i declare variable of model class EmailModel use of unassigned local variable* -- error found, time to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

`EmailModel emailModel;`

You are declaring emailModel, but you are not assigning it. You are then trying to use it without instantiating it.

You need to change it to `EmailModel emailModel = new EmailModel();`. The 'new' keyword creates a new instance in memory.

Answer (score 0):

@Muhammad farhan, it looks like this is downvoted but i'll try and get you moving in the right direction anyway. Change the top line to this and actually assign the variable.

```
EmailModel emailModel = new Emailmodel();
```